# Insert object to nested array

Tags: java, elasticsearch, nested

I'm trying to insert an object to a nested array through the java api, but I get the following error

*MapperParsingException[object mapping for [X] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value]*

doing it through Kibana as shown below the same script works.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**The java code is the following**

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("object", objectAsString);
Script script = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", "ctx._source.media.add(params.object)", params);
UpdateResponse result = elasticClient.prepareUpdate(indexName, "Type", documentId).setScript(script).execute().actionGet();
```

**Trhough Kibana**

```
POST index/document/id/_update
{
   "script": {
      "lang": "painless",
      "inline": "ctx._source.media.add(params.object)",
      "params": {
         "object": {
           "description" : "A second image",
      "height" :  5,
      "weight": 5,
      "name" :  "Test",
      "orientation" :  "Vertical",
       "url" :  "htttp://newurl.jpg",
      "tags":["first","second"],
      "type":"image"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The template mapping is the following:

```
"mappings": {
        "FOLDER_MODULE": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "publisherId": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "username": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "media": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "id": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "publisherId": {
                            "type": "short"
                        },
                        "tags": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "description": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "url": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "createdDate": {
                            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
                            "type": "date"
                        },
                        "height": {
                            "type": "float"
                        },
                        "width": {
                            "type": "float"
                        },
                        "weight": {
                            "type": "float"
                        },
                        "orientation": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "status": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "type": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "username": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: would you mind sharing your mapping?

Comment: @deerawan added the template mapping  to the description. I'm currently doing an http request from java in order to avoid this issue, using the same object (a json as string) in the request to elasticsearch